# `\n` character not rendering new line in jquery confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a jquery confirm plugin dialog, and when including new lines it doesn't show them. Any ideas on how to render them?

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").click( function() {
        $.confirm({
            theme: 'dark',
            title: 'Confirm Details',
            content: "This should \nbe a \nmulti-line \nstring",
            buttons: {
              confirm: function () {
              },
              cancel: function () {
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pa5s4zmb/

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1

One of the solutions would be to set CSS on the alert content to have [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) set to `pre-wrap`. You can do that using:

```
.jconfirm .jconfirm-box div.jconfirm-content-pane .jconfirm-content {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pa5s4zmb/1/

### Option 2

Alternatively, you could replace all `\n` characters with `<br>` which is allowed in an HTML alert.

This can be done like:

```
"This should \nbe a \nmulti-line \nstring".split('\n').join('<br>')
```

Here's the fiddle that replaces `\n` with `<br>`: https://jsfiddle.net/pa5s4zmb/2/

**Note**: I would generally prefer to use the second option here as it does not affect the CSS of library - and has lesser chances of breaking due to changes in future versions of the library.

Comment: Thank you! I feel like an idiot for not thinking to just use <br>

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `<br>` instead of `\n` and/or `&#13` are line breaks in text documents. `<br>` is structure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").click( function() {
        $.confirm({
            theme: 'dark',
            title: 'Confirm Details',
            content: "This should <br>be a <br>multi-line <br>string",
            buttons: {
              confirm: function () {
              },
              cancel: function () {
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**replace "\n" from "<br/>" tag** 
content: "This should <br>be a <br>multi-line <br>string",
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17749600)

Comment: @manman thankyou for your feedback. Next time i will take care of that